# Multiple inserts to temp table followed by single insert to material table OR multiple inserts straight to material table

Tags: sql

I've got a query that is structured as follows:

```
CREATE TempTable
...
INSERT INTO TempTable
...
INSERT INTO TempTable
...
INSERT INTO TempTable
...
INSERT INTO MaterialTable
SELECT *
FROM TempTable
```

Would it be more efficient to avoid using the temporary table and just do several inserts straight to the material table? i.e.

```
INSERT INTO MaterialTable
...
INSERT INTO MaterialTable
...
INSERT INTO MaterialTable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on the exact structure of the destination table and its indexes, and on the  nature of the processes that access the `MaterialTable` concurrently with your insertion.

- `TempTable` has no indexes; `MaterialTable` is likely to have several indexes. Depending on the amount of data being inserted and the number of individual inserts, copying from temp is likely to be faster, because a single multi-row check of each index needs to be performed.
- `TempTable` is invisible to outsiders; `MaterialTable` is likely to be accessed concurrently with your program. In cases like that, the amount of locking and unlocking would be smaller.
- Inserting all rows at once offers a better chance to parallelize the insertion for possibly an even faster insert.

None of that would matter much if `MaterialTable` is small (a few thousand rows). For larger tables the impact will be more significant, so I would recommend keeping the temp table approach when `MaterialTable` is expected to get large.

Answer (score 1):

Analyzing the execution plan and running tests is always your best bet. [Temp tables have their own overhead](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2002/derived-temp-tables/), so it really depends on a lot of factors. Take a look at [understanding execution plans](http://www.scarydba.com/2012/01/30/execution-plans-what-do-i-look-at/) and [INSERT performance between temp tables and a table variable](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13469/insert-performance-difference-between-temporary-tables-and-table-variable) for some background info.